# Tense in "le jour où ..."

Tags: temps-grammatical

"The day you feel lonely, you will learn to appreciate friends."

> Le jour où tu te sens seul(e), tu apprendras à apprécier des amis.

Does the first clause "Le jour où ..." need to be in the present or future tense? It will take place in the future, but in English the present tense is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Le jour où » introduit une proposition circonstancielle de temps, on pourrait le remplacer par « quand » ou « lorsque ».

Si on se réfère à [cette page](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-69930.php), il est dit que

> Lorsque les actions sont simultanées dans la principale et la subordonnée, les verbes de la proposition principale et de la subordonnée se mettent au même temps.

Selon cette règle, la traduction serait :

> Le jour où (Quand/Lorsque) tu te sentiras seul(e), tu apprendras à apprécier des amis.

On peut aussi employer le présent dans les deux propositions :

> Le jour où (Quand/Lorsque) tu te sens seul(e), tu apprends à apprécier des amis.

Voire même au passé :

> Le jour où (Quand/Lorsque) tu te sentis seul(e), tu appris à apprécier des amis.